# Parse string into its 3 parts: name, age, city

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing

I want to parse a line of text into three distinct parts (name, age, and city).

Example 1:

```
Muhammad Sholehhudin 24 Old Malang
```

Expected Result:

```
Name: Muhammad Sholehhudin
Age: 24 Old
City: Malang
```

The name and city substrings may contain one or more words.

Example 2:

```
Muhammad Sholehhudin Fauzi 51 Old Malang Kota
```

Expected Result:

```
Name: Muhammad Sholehhudin Fauzi
Age: 51 Old
City: Malang Kota
```

Comment: You need to try solving it yourself - that way you learn more. Show us what you have tried and what doesn't Work.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Addendum: What have you tried? - About your question, do you have a database of cities? There is no way Regex would know what is a city and what is a name, except, perhaps, in the edge cases. Finding a number way easier. With that said, can they be in any order? And, how should the software react to a malformed input? (say, for example, two numbers or more than 6 words, etc.) Addendum: Is the word "Old" required?

Comment: Once you can put it in words, you can devise a regex to split up strings on *character patterns*. It's not a magic word classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_split()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split up text based on a pattern.

The regex is split up into a few sections divided by the '|' witch means or.
 1. `(^([A-z]+\s){2,3})`
  -  the '^' means from the beginning of the string.
  - [A-z]+ = any letter from A-z the '+' means 1 or more times.
  - '{2,3}' = that pattern 2 or three times.
 2. `\d{1,3} Old` = any digit 1 to 3 times followed by 'Old'.
 3. `(\w+\s?){1,2}$`
  - '\w+' any word character one or more times.
  - '\s?' an optional space.
  - '$' means the end of the line

```
$input = $_POST['input_name'];

$pattern = '/((^([A-z]+ ){2,3})|(\d{1,3} Old)|(\w+\s?){1,2}$)/';

$matches = preg_split($pattern, $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$name = $matches[1];
$age = $matches[5];
$city = $matches[10];

echo 'Name: ' . $name;
echo ' Age: ' . $age;
echo ' City: ' . $city;
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your string on the solitary number followed by "Old" in the string -- including leading and trailing spaces, but only capture the number and Old". Tell `preg_split()` to retain the substring in the capture group and create a maximum of three elements in its returned value.

Use `vprintf()` to display the 3 elements in your desired format.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fSMpS))

```
$string = 'Muhammad Sholehhudin 24 Old Malang';

vprintf(
    'Name: %s, Age: %s, City: %s',
    preg_split(
        '/ (\d+ Old) /',
        $string,
        3,
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    )
);
```

Output:

```
Name: Muhammad Sholehhudin, Age: 24 Old, City: Malang
```

To remove the "Old" from the output string, you can either move `Old` outside of the capturing group in the regex pattern or change the middle `%s` to `%d`.